# ui-router component transitions issue

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I need complex animation for transition router states. I have to animate each element of state differently. But because of component, which loads template - it doesn't work as expected(because when you first time trigger state change - it will load template first, as a result ngAnimate will assign ng-enter and ng-enter-active before component will have children).
I've tried to add some delay for animation, without any result. Can you help me?

I've prepared plunkr. Just change state1/state2 two times(it will not work for first time).

plnkr.co/edit/pKKTAOnHXAJP37Srp5ol?p=preview

index.html

```
<a ui-sref="c1">state1</a>
<a ui-sref="c2">state2</a>

<div class="view-controller" ui-view>

</div>
```

component1.html

```
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="purple"></div>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
.component('component1', {
  template: '<div class="blue"></div><div class="green"></div>'
})
.component('component2', {
  templateUrl: 'component2.html'
})
.config(configFunction);

configFunction.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function configFunction($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('c1', {
    url: '/c1',
    template: '<component1></component1>'
  })
  .state('c2', {
    url: '/c2',
    template: '<component2></component2>'
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/c1')
}
```

style.css

```
[ui-view] {
  position: relative;
}

component1,
component2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter component2 .purple{
  transform: translate3d(-150px, 0, 0);
}
[ui-view].ng-enter component2 .yellow{
  transform: translate3d(0, -150px, 0);
}
[ui-view].ng-enter-active component2 .purple{
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
[ui-view].ng-enter-active component2 .yellow{
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

[ui-view].ng-enter {
  transition: 1s;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.purple {
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pKKTAOnHXAJP37Srp5ol?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't allow to insert url to plunker. It force me to use snippet instead, but it doesn't allow to add html template...

Comment: Got the answer finally?